# VB6 parameterized method with a return value over com interop

Tags: methods, vb6, return, com-interop, parameterized

I can't believe I'm having such a hard time with this, but can someone give me a quick example of a COM interface in C# that is to be called from VB6?  I want to pass parameters from VB6 to C#, and return a string to VB6.

Here's what I've got so far (not working):

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IMonitor
{
    string IPAddress(Int64 UserId, Enums.ClientTypes clientType);
}
```

I also tried:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IMonitor
{
    void IPAddress(Int64 UserId, Enums.ClientTypes clientType, [Out] string ipAddress);
}
```

Same error - Function or interface marked as restricted, or the function uses an Automation type not supported in Visual Basic.

FWIW, the ClientTypes enum works great in other VB6 code, so I don't believe the enum to be an issue.

Comment: See that Int64?  Yeah.... VB6 doesn't work with 64bit integers, now does it?  <HomerSimpson>DOH</HomerSimpson>

Comment: Change the interface to accept userid as a string then parse in c# or pass two vb6 longs as the hi/lo 32 bits.  Enums default to int which mmaps to a VB6 long.